# How can I allow my players to create, save and use moves?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to create a system to allow the players to create, save then use moves in Roblox Studio.

My first thought was to do this by letting them create animation files in Roblox Studio, but I'm not sure how this would be done, if possible, or if there were better ways to achieve this.

It's an rpg game, it will have a unarmed combat and sword combat, and like in character customization where do you see your character standing on the screen and you select accessories and skin color, you could move the limbs of you character and save this "animation" to use later in the game in a combat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Roblox Studio, but you could have players create animations in-game.

Breaking down your plan:

> where do you see your character standing on the screen, select accessories and skin color

I assume you have this sorted.

> move the limbs of your character

Pick points on the character (likely the joints) and put buttons on them. When the player clicks and holds a button, start moving the joint (and button) around.

> save this "animation"

Serialize all of the joint positions. See [serpent](https://github.com/pkulchenko/serpent) for a lua way to serialize. Roblox may have their own built in. If you let them just position the body, that's called a "pose". You could store multiple poses as "frames" of animation.

> use later in the game in combat

Deserialize the joint positions and tween from your idle pose to the animation pose. To support multiple frames of animation, you'll have to lerp between each frame and figure out what to do when you reach the end (loop or transition back to idle).

In addition to the positions of the joints, you may want to allow rotation and then you'll want to use "slerp" to tween between your rotations.